# Cardano-Cli How to Check Address Delegation Status?

Tags: cardano-cli, staking

is it possible in `cardano-cli` to check the status of delegation for any stake.addr?
is there a command that shows which pool a stake.addr is delegated to?
does that require the use of the heavy `ledger-state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cardano-cli query stake-address-info` does what you're looking for. It shows the registration status of a stake address, if it's delegated and how many rewards are available for withdrawal.